# SocketChannel.write() throwing OutOfMemoryError when attempting to write large buffer

Tags: java, android, nio, android-memory, socketchannel

My code throws an OutOfMemoryError when running the following line:

```java
int numBytes = socketChannel.write(_send_buffer);
```

where `socketChannel` is an instance of [java.nio.channels.SocketChannel](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel)

and `_send_buffer` is an instance of [java.nio.ByteBuffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer)

The code arrives at this point via a non-blocking selector write operation, and throws this on the first attempt to write when the capacity of `_send_buffer` is large. I have no issues with the code when `_send_buffer` is less than 20Mb, but when attempting to test this with larger buffers (e.g. > 100Mb) it fails.

According to the docs for [java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.write()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer)):

> An attempt is made to write up to r bytes to the channel, where r is the number of bytes remaining in the buffer, that is, src.remaining(), at the moment this method is invoked.
> Suppose that a byte sequence of length n is written, where 0 <= n <= r. This byte sequence will be transferred from the buffer starting at index p, where p is the buffer's position at the moment this method is invoked; the index of the last byte written will be p + n - 1. Upon return the buffer's position will be equal to p + n; its limit will not have changed.
> **Unless otherwise specified, a write operation will return only after writing all of the r requested bytes. Some types of channels, depending upon their state, may write only some of the bytes or possibly none at all. A socket channel in non-blocking mode, for example, cannot write any more bytes than are free in the socket's output buffer**.

My channels should be setup to be non-blocking, so I would think the write operation should only attempt to write up to the capacity of the socket's output buffer. As I did not previously specify this I tried setting it to 1024 bytes via the [setOption](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel#setOption(java.net.SocketOption%3CT%3E,%20T)) method with the [SO_SNDBUF](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/StandardSocketOptions#SO_SNDBUF) option. i.e:

```java
socketChannel.setOption(SO_SNDBUF, 1024);
```

Though I am still getting the OutOfMemoryError. Here is the full error message:

```
2021-04-22 11:52:44.260 11591-11733/jp.oist.abcvlib.serverLearning I/.serverLearnin: Clamp target GC heap from 195MB to 192MB
2021-04-22 11:52:44.260 11591-11733/jp.oist.abcvlib.serverLearning I/.serverLearnin: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 2508(64KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 171MB/192MB, paused 27us total 12.714ms
2021-04-22 11:52:44.261 11591-11733/jp.oist.abcvlib.serverLearning W/.serverLearnin: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 49915610 byte allocation with 21279560 free bytes and 20MB until OOM, target footprint 201326592, growth limit 201326592" (VmSize 5585608 kB)
2021-04-22 11:52:44.261 11591-11733/jp.oist.abcvlib.serverLearning I/.serverLearnin: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2021-04-22 11:52:44.261 11591-11733/jp.oist.abcvlib.serverLearning I/.serverLearnin: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
```

Now I can inline debug and stop at the write line and nothing crashes, so I believe there is no problem handling the memory requirement for the `_send_buffer` itself, but when attempting to write, something in the background is creating another allocation that's too much to handle.

Maybe I'm thinking about this wrong, and need to limit my `_send_buffer` size to something smaller, but I'd think there should be a way to limit the allocation made by the write command no? Or at least some way to allocate more of the Android memory to my app. I'm using a Pixel 3a, which according to the [specs](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_3a-9408.php) it should have 4GB of RAM. Now I realize that has to be shared with the rest of the system, but this is a bare bones test device (no games, personal apps, etc. are installed) so I'd assume I should have access to a fairly large chunk of that 4GB. As I'm crashing with a growth limit of 201,326,592 (according to the logcat above), it seems strange to me that I'm crashing at 0.2 / 4.0 = 5% of the spec'd memory.

Any tips in the right direction about a fundamental flaw in my approach, or recommendations for avoiding the OutOfMemoryError would be much appreciated!

### Edit 1:

Adding some code context as requested by comments. Note this is not a runnable example as the code base is quite large and I am not allowed to share it all due to company policies. Just note that the `_send_buffer` is has nothing to do with the sendbuffer of the socketChannel itself (i.e. what is referenced by [getSendBufferSize](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket#getSendBufferSize()), it is just a ByteBuffer that I use to bundle together everything before sending it via the channel. As I can't share all the code related to generating the contents of `_send_buffer` just note it is a ByteBuffer than can be very large (> 100Mb). If this is fundamentally a problem, then please point this out and why.

So with the above in mind, the NIO related code is pasted below. Note this is very prototype alpha code, so I apologize for the overload of comments and log statements.

#### SocketConnectionManager.java

(Essentially a Runnable in charge of the Selector)

Note the `sendMsgToServer` method is overridden (without modification) and called from the main Android activity (not shown). The `byte[] episode` arg is what gets wrapped into a `ByteBuffer` within `SocketMessage.java` (next section) which later gets put into the `_send_buffer` instance within the `write` method of `SocketMessage.java`.

```java
package jp.oist.abcvlib.util;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketOption;
import java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedSelectorException;
import java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.net.StandardSocketOptions.SO_SNDBUF;

public class SocketConnectionManager implements Runnable{

    private SocketChannel sc;
    private Selector selector;
    private SocketListener socketListener;
    private final String TAG = "SocketConnectionManager";
    private SocketMessage socketMessage;
    private final String serverIp;
    private final int serverPort;

    public SocketConnectionManager(SocketListener socketListener, String serverIp, int serverPort){
        this.socketListener = socketListener;
        this.serverIp = serverIp;
        this.serverPort = serverPort;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            selector = Selector.open();
            start_connection(serverIp, serverPort);
            do {
                int eventCount = selector.select(0);
                Set<SelectionKey> events = selector.selectedKeys(); // events is int representing how many keys have changed state
                if (eventCount != 0){
                    Set<SelectionKey> selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
                    for (SelectionKey selectedKey : selectedKeys){
                        try{
                            SocketMessage socketMessage = (SocketMessage) selectedKey.attachment();
                            socketMessage.process_events(selectedKey);
                        }catch (ClassCastException e){
                            Log.e(TAG,"Error", e);
                            Log.e(TAG, "selectedKey attachment not a SocketMessage type");
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (selector.isOpen()); //todo remember to close the selector somewhere

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error", e);
        }
    }

    private void start_connection(String serverIp, int serverPort){
        try {
            InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(serverIp, serverPort);
            sc = SocketChannel.open();
            sc.configureBlocking(false);
            sc.setOption(SO_SNDBUF, 1024);
            socketMessage = new SocketMessage(socketListener, sc, selector);

            Log.v(TAG, "registering with selector to connect");
            int ops = SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT;
            sc.register(selector, ops, socketMessage);

            Log.d(TAG, "Initializing connection with " + inetSocketAddress);
            boolean connected = sc.connect(inetSocketAddress);
            Log.v(TAG, "socketChannel.isConnected ? : " + sc.isConnected());

        } catch (IOException | ClosedSelectorException | IllegalBlockingModeException
                | CancelledKeyException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Initial socket connect and registration:", e);
        }
    }

    public void sendMsgToServer(byte[] episode){
        boolean writeSuccess = socketMessage.addEpisodeToWriteBuffer(episode);
    }

    /**
     * Should be called prior to exiting app to ensure zombie threads don't remain in memory.
     */
    public void close(){
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "Closing connection: " + sc.getRemoteAddress());
            selector.close();
            sc.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

#### SocketMessage.java

This is greatly inspired from the example Python code given [here](https://github.com/realpython/materials/tree/master/python-sockets-tutorial), in particular the `libclient.py` and `app-client.py`. This is because the server is running python code and clients are running Java. So if you want the reasoning behind why things are the way they are, reference the [RealPython](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) socket tutorial. I essentially used the app-server.py as a template for my code, and translated (with modifications) to Java for the clients.

```java
package jp.oist.abcvlib.util;

import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Vector;

public class SocketMessage {
    
    private final SocketChannel sc;
    private final Selector selector;
    private final ByteBuffer _recv_buffer;
    private ByteBuffer _send_buffer;
    private int _jsonheader_len = 0;
    private JSONObject jsonHeaderRead; // Will tell Java at which points in msgContent each model lies (e.g. model1 is from 0 to 1018, model2 is from 1019 to 2034, etc.)
    private byte[] jsonHeaderBytes;
    private ByteBuffer msgContent; // Should contain ALL model files. Parse to individual files after reading
    private final Vector<ByteBuffer> writeBufferVector = new Vector<>(); // List of episodes
    private final String TAG = "SocketConnectionManager";
    private JSONObject jsonHeaderWrite;
    private boolean msgReadComplete = false;
    private SocketListener socketListener;
    private long socketWriteTimeStart;
    private long socketReadTimeStart;


    public SocketMessage(SocketListener socketListener, SocketChannel sc, Selector selector){
        this.socketListener = socketListener;
        this.sc = sc;
        this.selector = selector;
        this._recv_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        this._send_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    }

    public void process_events(SelectionKey selectionKey){
        SocketChannel sc = (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();
//        Log.i(TAG, "process_events");
        try{
            if (selectionKey.isConnectable()){
                sc.finishConnect();
                Log.d(TAG, "Finished connecting to " + ((SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel()).getRemoteAddress());
                Log.v(TAG, "socketChannel.isConnected ? : " + sc.isConnected());

            }
            if (selectionKey.isWritable()){
//                Log.i(TAG, "write event");
                write(selectionKey);
            }
            if (selectionKey.isReadable()){
//                Log.i(TAG, "read event");
                read(selectionKey);
//                int ops = SelectionKey.OP_WRITE;
//                sc.register(selectionKey.selector(), ops, selectionKey.attachment());
            }

        } catch (ClassCastException | IOException | JSONException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"Error", e);
        }
    }

    private void read(SelectionKey selectionKey) throws IOException, JSONException {

        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();

        while(!msgReadComplete){
            // At this point the _recv_buffer should have been cleared (pointer 0 limit=cap, no mark)
            int bitsRead = socketChannel.read(_recv_buffer);

            if (bitsRead > 0 || _recv_buffer.position() > 0){
                if (bitsRead > 0){
//                    Log.v(TAG, "Read " + bitsRead + " bytes from " + socketChannel.getRemoteAddress());
                }

                // If you have not determined the length of the header via the 2 byte short protoheader,
                // try to determine it, though there is no gaurantee it will have enough bytes. So it may
                // pass through this if statement multiple times. Only after it has been read will
                // _jsonheader_len have a non-zero length;
                if (this._jsonheader_len == 0){
                    socketReadTimeStart = System.nanoTime();
                    process_protoheader();
                }
                // _jsonheader_len will only be larger than 0 if set properly (finished being set).
                // jsonHeaderRead will be null until the buffer gathering it has filled and converted it to
                // a JSONobject.
                else if (this.jsonHeaderRead == null){
                    process_jsonheader();
                }
                else if (!msgReadComplete){
                    process_msgContent(selectionKey);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "bitsRead but don't know what to do with them");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void write(SelectionKey selectionKey) throws IOException, JSONException {

        if (!writeBufferVector.isEmpty()){
            SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();

            Log.v(TAG, "writeBufferVector contains data");

            if (jsonHeaderWrite == null){
                int numBytesToWrite = writeBufferVector.get(0).limit();

                // Create JSONHeader containing length of episode in Bytes
                Log.v(TAG, "generating jsonheader");
                jsonHeaderWrite = generate_jsonheader(numBytesToWrite);
                byte[] jsonBytes = jsonHeaderWrite.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                // Encode length of JSONHeader to first two bytes and write to socketChannel
                int jsonLength = jsonBytes.length;

                // Add up length of protoHeader, JSONheader and episode bytes
                int totalNumBytesToWrite = Integer.BYTES + jsonLength + numBytesToWrite;

                // Create new buffer that compiles protoHeader, JsonHeader, and Episode
                _send_buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(totalNumBytesToWrite);

                Log.v(TAG, "Assembling _send_buffer");
                // Assemble all bytes and flip to prepare to read
                _send_buffer.putInt(jsonLength);
                _send_buffer.put(jsonBytes);
                _send_buffer.put(writeBufferVector.get(0));
                _send_buffer.flip();

                Log.d(TAG, "Writing to server ...");

                // Write Bytes to socketChannel //todo shouldn't be while as should be non-blocking
                if (_send_buffer.remaining() > 0){
                    int numBytes = socketChannel.write(_send_buffer); // todo memory dump error here!
                    int percentDone = (int) Math.ceil((((double) _send_buffer.limit() - (double) _send_buffer.remaining())
                            / (double) _send_buffer.limit()) * 100);
                    int total = _send_buffer.limit() / 1000000;
//                    Log.d(TAG, "Sent " + percentDone + "% of " + total + "Mb to " + socketChannel.getRemoteAddress());
                }
            } else{
                // Write Bytes to socketChannel
                if (_send_buffer.remaining() > 0){
                    socketChannel.write(_send_buffer);
                }
            }
            if (_send_buffer.remaining() == 0){
                int total = _send_buffer.limit() / 1000000;
                double timeTaken = (System.nanoTime() - socketWriteTimeStart) * 10e-10;
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
                df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
                Log.i(TAG, "Sent " + total + "Mb in " + df.format(timeTaken) + "s");
                // Remove episode from buffer so as to not write it again.
                writeBufferVector.remove(0);
                // Clear sending buffer
                _send_buffer.clear();
                // make null so as to catch the initial if statement to write a new one.
                jsonHeaderWrite = null;

                // Set socket to read now that writing has finished.
                Log.d(TAG, "Reading from server ...");
                int ops = SelectionKey.OP_READ;
                sc.register(selectionKey.selector(), ops, selectionKey.attachment());
            }

        }
    }

    private JSONObject generate_jsonheader(int numBytesToWrite) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject jsonHeader = new JSONObject();

        jsonHeader.put("byteorder", ByteOrder.nativeOrder().toString());
        jsonHeader.put("content-length", numBytesToWrite);
        jsonHeader.put("content-type", "flatbuffer"); // todo Change to flatbuffer later
        jsonHeader.put("content-encoding", "flatbuffer"); //Change to flatbuffer later
        return jsonHeader;
    }

    /**
     * recv_buffer may contain 0, 1, or several bytes. If it has more than hdrlen, then process
     * the first two bytes to obtain the length of the jsonheader. Else exit this function and
     * read from the buffer again until it fills past length hdrlen.
     */
    private void process_protoheader() {
        Log.v(TAG, "processing protoheader");
        int hdrlen = 2;
        if (_recv_buffer.position() >= hdrlen){
            _recv_buffer.flip(); //pos at 0 and limit set to bitsRead
            _jsonheader_len = _recv_buffer.getShort(); // Read 2 bytes converts to short and move pos to 2
            // allocate new ByteBuffer to store full jsonheader
            jsonHeaderBytes = new byte[_jsonheader_len];

            _recv_buffer.compact();

            Log.v(TAG, "finished processing protoheader");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  As with the process_protoheader we will check if _recv_buffer contains enough bytes to
     *  generate the jsonHeader objects, and if not, leave it alone and read more from socket.
     */
    private void process_jsonheader() throws JSONException {

        Log.v(TAG, "processing jsonheader");

        // If you have enough bytes in the _recv_buffer to write out the jsonHeader
        if (_jsonheader_len - _recv_buffer.position() < 0){
            _recv_buffer.flip();
            _recv_buffer.get(jsonHeaderBytes);
            // jsonheaderBuffer should now be full and ready to convert to a JSONobject
            jsonHeaderRead = new JSONObject(new String(jsonHeaderBytes));
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONheader from server: " + jsonHeaderRead.toString());

            try{
                int msgLength = (int) jsonHeaderRead.get("content-length");
                msgContent = ByteBuffer.allocate(msgLength);
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get content-length from jsonHeader sent from server", e);
            }
        }
        // Else return to selector and read more bytes into the _recv_buffer

        // If there are any bytes left over (part of the msg) then move them to the front of the buffer
        // to prepare for another read from the socket
        _recv_buffer.compact();
    }

    /**
     * Here a bit different as it may take multiple full _recv_buffers to fill the msgContent.
     * So check if msgContent.remaining is larger than 0 and if so, dump everything from _recv_buffer to it
     * @param selectionKey : Used to reference the instance and selector
     * @throws ClosedChannelException :
     */
    private void process_msgContent(SelectionKey selectionKey) throws IOException {

        if (msgContent.remaining() > 0){
            _recv_buffer.flip(); //pos at 0 and limit set to bitsRead set ready to read
            msgContent.put(_recv_buffer);
            _recv_buffer.clear();
        }

        if (msgContent.remaining() == 0){
            // msgContent should now be full and ready to convert to a various model files.
            socketListener.onServerReadSuccess(jsonHeaderRead, msgContent);

            // Clear for next round of communication
            _recv_buffer.clear();
            _jsonheader_len = 0;
            jsonHeaderRead = null;
            msgContent.clear();

            int totalBytes = msgContent.capacity() / 1000000;
            double timeTaken = (System.nanoTime() - socketReadTimeStart) * 10e-10;
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
            df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            Log.i(TAG, "Entire message containing " + totalBytes + "Mb recv'd in " + df.format(timeTaken) + "s");

            msgReadComplete = true;

            // Set socket to write now that reading has finished.
            int ops = SelectionKey.OP_WRITE;
            sc.register(selectionKey.selector(), ops, selectionKey.attachment());
        }
    }

    //todo should send this to the mainactivity listener so it can be customized/overridden
    private void onNewMessageFromServer(){
        // Take info from JSONheader to parse msgContent into individual model files

        // After parsing all models notify MainActivity that models have been updated
    }

    // todo should be able deal with ByteBuffer from FlatBuffer rather than byte[]
    public boolean addEpisodeToWriteBuffer(byte[] episode){
        boolean success = false;
        try{
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(episode);
            success = writeBufferVector.add(bb);
            Log.v(TAG, "Added data to writeBuffer");
            int ops = SelectionKey.OP_WRITE;
            socketWriteTimeStart = System.nanoTime();
            sc.register(selector, ops, this);
            // I want this to trigger the selector that this channel is writeReady.
        } catch (NullPointerException | ClosedChannelException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"Error", e);
            Log.e(TAG, "SocketConnectionManager.data not initialized yet");
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code please. And why are you trying to write such huge buffers?

Comment: I'll work on creating a minimal working example if you think it is necessary as the code base is quite large. The huge buffer represents a complete "episode" of data used in a reinforcement learning algorithm. This includes all sorts of sensor data (wheel velocities, sound data, image data, etc.). It is convenient to send them as a single package in order to keep the code generalized for any sort of data within the episode. Yes, I could send it in pieces, but this would greatly complicate the code and make it much harder to maintain if the contents of the episode change (likely).

Comment: @user207421 please see Edit 1 header. Let me know if you need further context on the contents of the `episode` or otherwise and I can try to give you as much info as possible with the constraints of our company policies.

Comment: Much too much code to demonstrate a problem.

Comment: `addEpisodeToWriteBuffer(byte[] episode){
        boolean success = false;
        try{
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(episode);
            success = writeBufferVector.add(bb);` Say epicode is 100 MB. Then you copy it to bb. That is again at least 100 MB occupied of memory. Then you add bb to something. Do you add a pointer or 100MB bytes? If so then only this costs you already 300 MB. That does not look like a good approach.

Comment: Even if you want to write a very big buffer then do not use only one write command. Make a loop and send/write small chunks of that buffer until done.

Comment: @blackapps I originally didn't put all the code, and just highlighted the lines in which the problem was known to occur. I updated based on a request for the code and gave as summary of where in the code to look for the details originally referenced. Not sure how I can make everyone happy at once ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. Also I don't write everything in a single command. It writes in chunks via the selector. Typically it is writing in chunks of 2 to 8kB. Yeah I agree that wrapping to the bb var is not ideal. Thanks for pointing it out though. I noted this in the comment above that method as a todo.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview#RestrictingMemory) in the Android Docs, which answers the question of why I get the OutOfMemoryError.

> To maintain a functional multi-tasking environment, Android sets a hard limit on the heap size for each app. The exact heap size limit varies between devices based on how much RAM the device has available overall. If your app has reached the heap capacity and tries to allocate more memory, it can receive an OutOfMemoryError.

> In some cases, you might want to query the system to determine exactly how much heap space you have available on the current device—for example, to determine how much data is safe to keep in a cache. You can query the system for this figure by calling getMemoryClass(). This method returns an integer indicating the number of megabytes available for your app's heap.

After running the [ActivityManager.getMemoryClass](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getMemoryClass()) method, I see for my Pixel 3a I have a hard limit of 192 MB. As I was trying to allocate just over 200 MB, I hit this limit.

I also checked the [ActivityManager.getLargeMemoryClass](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getLargeMemoryClass()) and see I have a hard limit of 512 MB. So I can set my app to have a "largeHeap", but despite having 4GB of RAM, I have a hard limit of 512 MB I need to work around.

Unless someone else knows any way around this, I'll have to write some logic to piecewise write the `episode` to file if it goes above a certain point, and piecewise send it over the channel later. This will slow things down a fair bit I guess, so if anyone has an answer that can avoid this, or tell me why this won't slow things down if done properly, then I'm happy to give you the answer. Just posting this as an answer as it does answer my original question, but rather unsatisfactorily.

Comment: Why not piecewise send it over the channel as you accumulate it? Much quicker, much less latency, much less memory.

Comment: The reason being that the main chunk of the episode is a [flatbuffer](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/) object. Not sure if you are familiar with them, but I'm not sure how to stream them piecewise (if its possible). The reason I'm using them rather than JSON is I originally faced a memory issue when trying to serialize the JSONobject and was pointed towards using flatbuffers as a solution (no need to serialize). Rereading my answer, I see that I'd face the same issue if trying to piecewise write to file... hmmm have to rethink.